Can we use stochastic process theory (counting processes) for mortality data?
Suppose I have a counting process $N(t)$ that counts the number of events over some time index $T=(0,\tau]$. Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F})$ is the underlying measurable space and $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{R})$ the image space, where $\mathscr{F}$ is a $\sigma$-field of subsets of $\Omega$ and $\mathscr{R}$ the linear Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. Then $N:\Omega\times T\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a stochastic process.
My interest lies in Poisson processes, which require a particular set of assumptions for $N(t)$: namely $0<t_{1}<t_{2}<\cdots < t_{k}$ the increments $\Delta_{t_{0},t_{1}}:=N_{t_{1}}, \Delta_{t_{1},t_{2}}:=N_{t_{2}}-N_{t_{1}},...,\Delta_{t_{k-1},t_{k}}:=N_{t_{k}}-N_{t_{k-1}}$ are independent and for any $s<t$ the increment $\Delta_{s,t}=N(t)-N(s)$ has law $\mathcal{L}(\Delta_{s,t})=Poiss(\lambda (t-s))$. I am following "Probability and Measure" by Billingsley (1995) who has a nice piece on the equivalence of these assumptions to an alternate set, namely that the event times giving rise to the event counts, are independent and exponentially distributed with rate parameter $\lambda$. It turns out that for these two sets of assumptions to be equivalent requires the following four conditions;

For each $\omega\in \Omega$, $N(t,\omega)\geq 0$
For each $\omega\in \Omega$, $N(t,\omega)\longrightarrow \infty$ as $t\longrightarrow\infty$
For each $\omega\in \Omega$ the path $N(\cdot,\omega)$ is nondecreasing and right-continuous
At any points of discontinuity $d$, the saltus (jump) satisfies $N(d,\omega)-\text{sup}_{s<d}N(s,\omega)=1$ (i.e for each $\omega\in\Omega$ the jump from the left is precisely unity)

My interest is to work with the prototype counting process above, but for a set of $i=1,...,n$ people, so that $N_{i}(t)$ denotes the $i^{th}$ process. For simplicity assume the $n$ process are independent. The setting is either mortality event counts, or disease event counts, and it is mortality that is causing me the biggest problem. In essence I am unclear about condition (2), and whether data being analysed has to satisfy this, which is impossible (for both types of processes) since we can never follow-up people for infinite time, that is $N_{i}(t)$ can only ever be evaluated for $t<\infty$.
Given all the things we assume in statistics the above "problem" for disease event counts I can live with - i.e I think nothing of assuming the existence of random effects in longitudinal modelling as a tool to understand the data better. However for mortality I have a very big problem since even if I "imagine" I could follow-up people for infinite time, they can only die once. Presumably censoring has to be anticipated to be the solution, i.e. they could have observed more events but were lost to follow-up, or admin-censored at finite $\tau$.
My thoughts on censoring are that this censoring relates to estimating $\lambda$ (and other parameters linked to it, such as regression effects), but conditions (1)-(4) are on the un-censored process. If so then censoring should not "make OK" the use of a counting process for mortality, since $N_{i}(t)\in\{0,1\}$ however large $t$ becomes - i.e we should start instead with a process that can give infinite counts over infintie time, and then truncate to either zero or one event - but how to interpret such a counting process for mortality? I have seen somewhere for rare death rates an argument involving imagining replacing a person with an identical person following each death to justify ignoring censoring and using Poisson distribution. This also relies on very few censoring events.
I am aware $N(t)=\sum_{i}N_{i}(t)$ is the aggregate counting process used in modelling (i.e. Cox model or Anderson-Gill model for recurrent events), but for mortality $N$ can never satisfy (2) even for $\tau=\infty$ unless $N\longrightarrow\infty$. This seems an incorrect way to meet condition (2), since this looks like we are using a sample of $n$ degenerate counting processes.

This section just shows the sort of theory I am reading that uses the counting process theory. I am using "Survival and Event History analysis" (Aalen et al, 2008). Unfortunately Billinglsey is not concerned with modelling data, and so does not discuss mortality. Furthermore as far as I can tell, the Aalen book seems to gloss over the mortality issue.
A filtration $\mathfrak{F}:=\{\mathscr{F}_{t}\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a non-decreasing family of sub-$\sigma$-fields of an underlying $\sigma$-field $\mathscr{F}$ (of subsets of $\Omega$): $\mathscr{F}_{s}\subseteq\mathscr{F}_{t}\subseteq\mathscr{F}$ for all $0\leq s\leq t <\infty$ where $\mathscr{F}_{0}=\mathscr{F}$. Then the intensity rate $\lambda(t)$ of some disease in the following sense.
If we assume the following model for the "infinitesimal increment" of $N(t)$ in $[t,t+dt)$
$$E[d N(t)||\mathscr{F}_{t^{-}}]=\lambda(t)dt$$
where $\mathscr{F}_{t^{-}}$ is the information "just before" time $t$. Then for the residual $M(t)$ defined as
$$M(t)=N(t)-\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(s)ds$$
we than have
$$E[dM(t)||\mathscr{F}_{t^{-}}]=E[d N(t)||\mathscr{F}_{t^{-}}]-\lambda(t)dt\\
  \hspace{50pt}=\lambda(t)dt-\lambda(t)dt=0$$
which is the definition of a martingale. This is start of various arguments for CLT type theorems since martingales "tend to converge" so I have read. These are prototype martingales, so we in fact have $M_{i}(t)$ for each person and an aggregate martingale $M(t)=\sum_{i}M_{i}(t)$

Update: adding in example of approximate Poisson inference for rare events due to interest in comments
One reference is "Statistical methods in cancer research, Volume II" by Breslow and Day, 1987. The data for inference is a "table" of data from $n$ people stratified into J cells believed to provide near constant risk of death - i.e cell $j$ might be $n_{j}<n$ people in a particular age range and born in a particular year range. The follow-up time of each subject is capped at some time $T_{i}$ leading to admin censoring, but also non-admin censoring may arise (B&D are using a fixed cut-off date so that late entry people have short $T_{i}$, rather than fixed maximum follow-up time for each person).
On p132 they discuss how to simplify inference about the $j^{th}$ rate $\lambda_{j}$ of death interpreted as $p_{j}(t)=\lambda_{j}(t) dt$ being the instantaneous probability any person dies in the infinitesimal interval of time $(t,t+dt)$.
This bit is taken from Volume I (p51) about building a survival likelihood function by starting with rates. If $\Lambda_{j}(t)=\int_{0}^{t}\lambda_{j}(s) ds$, and if $P_{j}(t)$ denotes the net probability person $i$ dies between time $0$ and $t$ then the following relationship is assumed;
$$\lambda_{j}(t)=\frac{1}{1-P_{j}(t)}\times\frac{dP_{j}(t)}{dt},$$
which expresses $\lambda_{j}(t)$ as the rate of increase of $P_{j}(t)$ expressed relative to the proportion of people still at risk, which implies
$$P_{j}(t)=1-\exp(-\Lambda_{j}(t))$$
Then since $p_{j}(t)=(d/dt)P_{j}(t)$ we have
$$p_{j}(t)=\exp(-\Lambda_{j}(t))$$
Back to Volume II (p132). Since the risk in cell $j$ is constant over time we have $\lambda_{j}(t):=\lambda$ and thus $\Lambda_{j}(t)=\lambda_{j}t$. If $(t_{i},\delta_{i})$ represent the event times $t_{i}$ and censoring flag $\delta_{i}$ for person $i$ then $(t_{i},\delta_{i})$, $i=1,...,n_{j}$  is the data. Then a person surviving until withdrawal contributes the following term to the likelihood function;
$$Pr[t_{i}=T_{i},\delta_{i}=0]=1-p_{j}(t)=1-\exp(-\lambda_{j} t_{i}),$$
whilst a person dying in the interval $(0,t_{i}]\subseteq (0, T_{i}]$ contributes the following term to the likelihood function;
$$f[t_{i}|\delta_{i}=0]=\lambda_{j}\exp(-\lambda_{j} t_{i})$$
where $f$ is the exponential density function (to be honest I struggle with this concept of mixing densities and probabilities, but have seen a justification before on this site). Given the above two terms, the log-likelihood is
$$L(\lambda_{j})=\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}}\left(\delta_{i}\log(\lambda_{j})-t_{i}\lambda_{j}\right)=d_{j}\log (\lambda_{j})-T_{j}\lambda_{j},$$
where $d_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}}\delta_{j}$ denotes the total deaths and $T_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}}t_{j}$ the total person-time of follow-up.
We can differentiate $L(\lambda_{j})$ to find the MLE of $\hat{\lambda}_{j}=d_{j}/T_{j}$. However due to truncated follow-up times the distribution of $\hat{\lambda}_{j}$ is very complex, leading to the following suggested simplification by using Poisson inference.
It seems B&D only permit censoring due to $T_{i}<t_{i}$, however given this should be non-informative, I imagine we can permit any non-informative censoring in what follows?
After each death replace each person with "an identical person" at the time of death. Then hypothetically the number of deaths $d_{ij}$ per person take the range $d_{ij}\in\{0,1,2,...\}$ and the follow-up time would always be $T_{i}$ (similarly if we replaced censorings as well ?). Then
$$d_{j}=\sum_{i=1}^{n_{j}}d_{ij}\sim Poiss(\lambda_{j}T_{j})$$
B&D conclude the above Poisson distribution will give good inference for the Poisson MLE of $\hat{\lambda}_{j}=d_{j}/T_{j}$ which is the same estimator form as from the censored exponential data, if $\lambda_{j}$ is small and the follow-up time is chosen such that only a fraction of the people are expected to die in the study period.

This whole post sounds like you never studied a single book such as Modelling Mortality with Actuarial Applications, A. Macdonald,  S.J. Richards, I.D. Currie.

Why do you want to model the mortality process as a Poisson process? In section 1.1.2 of the book you mentioned, Aalen models survival time as a random variable $T$ and considers estimating the survival curve, hazard rate etc. You could model the mortality process of individual $i$ as $N_i(t) = I_{T \leq t}$.

@pabk thanks. I am curious about making the Poisson assumption work for rare events, rather than being wedded to the idea. As stated in the post, some author's in a non-counting process set-up argue for Poisson distribution for death counts through assuming we can replace a person when they are censored with an "exact replica", so that no censoring occurs. This censoring can also be following a death. Thus the accuracy of this depends on low death and censoring rate. But how, if at all, does this apply to a Poisson process - can/should the same "replica people" assumption be used?

@KurtG. thanks, and you are correct about your assertion. Unfortunately I do not have a copy but will try and track down.

You may want to explain what you mean by censoring and who those authors/papers are that suggest to replace a censored person with an exact replica. About mortality: have you ever looked at an actuarial table that contains the statistical data about the survival probabilities of persons of a certain age? A person can die only once and (as far as we know) cannot live forever. So the simplest model for a single person is what pabk wrote above plus that the hazard rate increases with the person's age.

@KurtG. Once again thanks. As stated earlier a few times, I am interested in the Poisson process and how to apply it, or not, to mortality. Thus I am not interested in the simplest method (although point taken, simpler methods are probably more appropriate). I have added in an explanation of the "replacement" scheme.

@KurtG. After your comments about actuarial theory, I started searching for this and came across a paper that seems to be what I wanted: applying the Poisson process to mortality data. $\url{https://www.actuaries.org.uk/system/files/documents/pdf/0255-0263.pdf}$ which is a paper called "Some applications of the poisson distribution in mortality studies" by W.F. Scott and is available online
